# Error in Emacs: invalid search bound (wrong side of point)

Tags: debugging, emacs, org-mode

I get this error when trying to match the tags "PRIORITY=\"A\"" in org-agenda emacs.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
          '(("c" "Simple agenda view"
             ((tags "PRIORITY=\"A\""
                    ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done))
                     (org-agenda-overriding-header "High-priority unfinished tasks:")))

              (agenda "")
              (alltodo "")))))
```

The debugger returns the following information:

```
**Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)")

  re-search-forward("[[<]\\([0-9]\\{4\\}-[0-9]\\{2\\}-[0-9]\\{2\\} ?[^]\15\n>]*?\\..." 37 t)
  #f(compiled-function (specific end ts) #<bytecode 0x1591cc61959d>)(nil 37 nil)
  org-entry-properties(nil)
  org-cached-entry-get(nil "PRIORITY")
  (or (org-cached-entry-get nil "PRIORITY") "")
  (string= (or (org-cached-entry-get nil "PRIORITY") "") "A")
  (and (string= (or (org-cached-entry-get nil "PRIORITY") "") "A"))
  (or (and (string= (or (org-cached-entry-get nil "PRIORITY") "") "A")))
  (progn (setq org-cached-props nil) (or (and (string= (or (org-cached-entry-get nil "PRIORITY") "") "A"))))
  (lambda (todo tags-list level) (progn (setq org-cached-props nil) (or (and (string= (or (org-cached-entry-get nil "PRIORITY") "") "A")))))("TODO" nil 1)
  org-scan-tags(agenda (lambda (todo tags-list level) (progn (setq org-cached-props nil) (or (and (string= (or (org-cached-entry-get nil "PRIORITY") "") "A"))))) nil)
  org-tags-view(nil "PRIORITY=\"A\"")
  (let ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done)) (org-agenda-overriding-header "High-priority unfinished tasks:")) (org-tags-view current-prefix-arg match))
  (let nil (let ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done)) (org-agenda-overriding-header "High-priority unfinished tasks:")) (org-tags-view current-prefix-arg match)))
  eval((let nil (let ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done)) (org-agenda-overriding-header "High-priority unfinished tasks:")) (org-tags-view current-prefix-arg match))))
  org-let2(nil ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done)) (org-agenda-overriding-header "High-priority unfinished tasks:")) (org-tags-view current-prefix-arg match))
  org-agenda-run-series("Simple agenda view" (((tags "PRIORITY=\"A\"" ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if ... ...)) (org-agenda-overriding-header "High-priority unfinished tasks:"))) (agenda "") (alltodo ""))))
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda)**
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EMACS version: 28.0.50

ORG-version: 9.3

Comment: Please don't pose the same question in StackOverflow and in emacs.SE. Choose one or the other, and please delete the one don't choose. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments, I found that ((tags "PRIORITY=\"A\"")) crates this error. I rewrote the code in a way that it does not have to use this condition. My version to achieve the same goal:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "Simple agenda view" ((alltodo ""
         ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if  'notregexp "\\[#A\\]" 'todo 'done))
              (org-agenda-overriding-header "High-priority unfinished tasks:")))


         ;((tags-todo "+PRIORITY=\"A\""
          (agenda "")
          (alltodo ""
                   ((org-agenda-skip-function
                     '(or (air-org-skip-subtree-if-priority ?A)
                          (org-agenda-skip-if nil '(scheduled deadline))))))))))
```